# Unir múltiples csv en un dataframe

Tags: pandas, concat

Tengo una carpeta con alrededor de 90 csv. Quiero unirlos en un único dataframe y que no solo me encadene cada csv sino que combine los datos de cada fila en función de la columna principal, en este caso 'Name'. Cada uno de los csv tiene la siguiente estructura (simplifico porque cada df tiene muchas más columnas):

CSV1:

```
    Name       Team    Passes     Shots
1   Player 1    Oly       20        5
2   Player 2    PSG        6        4
3   Player 3    Lil        3        6
```

CSV2:

```
    Name       Team    Passes     Shots
1   Player 4    Par       22        4
2   Player 5    ATM        7        3
3   Player 6    Fer        9        1
```

CSV3:

```
    Name       Team    Assists     Goals
1   Player 1    Oly       2         3
2   Player 2    PSG       1         4
3   Player 3    Lil       1         1
```

CSV4:

```
    Name       Team    Assists     Goals
1   Player 4    Par       3         1
2   Player 5    ATM       4         2
3   Player 6    Fer       5         3
```

El resultado final que busco es:

```
    Name       Team    Passes     Shots    Assists    Goals
1   Player 1    Oly       20        5         2         3
2   Player 2    PSG        6        4         1         4
3   Player 3    Lil        3        6         1         1
4   Player 4    Par       22        4         3         1
5   Player 5    ATM        7        3         4         2
6   Player 6    Fer        9        1         5         3
```

Sin embargo, el resultado que encuentro es el siguiente:

```
    Name       Team    Passes     Shots    Assists    Goals
1   Player 1    Oly       20        5        NaN       NaN
2   Player 2    PSG        6        4        NaN       NaN
3   Player 3    Lil        3        6        NaN       NaN
4   Player 4    Par       22        4        NaN       NaN
5   Player 5    ATM        7        3        NaN       NaN
6   Player 6    Fer        9        1        NaN       NaN
7   Player 1    Oly      NaN       NaN        2         3
8   Player 2    PSG      NaN       NaN        1         4
9   Player 3    Lil      NaN       NaN        1         1
10  Player 4    Par      NaN       NaN        3         1
11  Player 5    ATM      NaN       NaN        4         2
12  Player 6    Fer      NaN       NaN        5         3
```

Éste es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
from os import listdir

filepaths = [f for f in listdir("./") if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths), ignore_index=True)
```

Estoy muy cerca de conseguirlo pero algo se me escapa. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Utiliza join. No hagas  pd.read  en linea sino que lleva a  un dfn. Debes tener el df principal y los dfn que vas incorporando. luego le haces: df.join(dfn.set_index('Name'),on="Name", how='outer'). Ahora, si logras hacerlos como tienes  tu concat me pasas para ver como lo hiciste

Comment: Te lo pasaría encantado pero no lo logré :( Intenté hacer un df principal con solo datos comunes en todos los csv (Name, Team, etc) llamado dfppal. Después intenté con este código `dfppal1 = pd.concat(map(dfppal.join(filepaths.set_index('Name'),on="Name", how='outer')), ignore_index=True)` pero recibo `'list' object has no attribute 'set_index'` ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Se pueden hacer 2 cosas, 1 hacer lo quebhaces y luego eliminar los datos duplicados o 2 usar un merge

Comment: Con los datos que has puesto arriba lo hago y te lo paso. Ah pero mejor era en bloque for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo dejo como una respuesta, porque en este caso aplica..

Utilizando tu código, solo deberías agrupar por `Name` y `Team`, y luego aplicarle `sum` a todas las columnas. Como decía.. en este caso aplica ya que solo posees valores `NaN`.

Al final te quedaría:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Team']).sum().reset_index()



            Name    Team    Passes  Shots   Assists Goals
   0      Player 1   Oly    20.0    5.0     2.0      3.0
   1      Player 2   PSG    6.0      4.0    1.0      4.0
   2      Player 3   Lil    3.0      6.0    1.0      1.0
   3      Player 4   Par    22.0     4.0    3.0      1.0
   4      Player 5   ATM    7.0      3.0    4.0      2.0
   5      Player 6   Fer    9.0      1.0    5.0      3.0
```

luego puedes convertir las columnas del tipo de dato `float` a `int` si quieres..

```
df[['Passes','Shots','Assists','Goals']] = df[['Passes','Shots','Assists','Goals']].astype(int)
```

Comment: Perfecto, esto era lo que buscaba. Tanto groupby como sum han sido la clave. No sé cuántas horas he estado buscando la solución, me estaba volviendo loco jaja Mil gracias